# Squared Sharpe Ratio - Fama and French

Tags: sharpe-ratio, fama-french

I am investigating various versions of nested and nonnested Fama and French factor models. Performance of the models is compared on the basis of Squared Sharpe Ratios. [Bariallas et al. (2020, JFQA)](https://www.cambridge.org/core/journals/journal-of-financial-and-quantitative-analysis/article/model-comparison-with-sharpe-ratios/7AAB79D48CC55E0AD1BC6C8AABD6F5D9) propose a test that does only require the factors as inputs and does not rely on test assets. However, I can not quite get my head around how Squared Sharpe Ratios are calculated in this case. Are they calculated for each factor individually and then summed up? This approach seems flawed, and if any, this would only make sense if the models that are compared have the same number of factors.

Comment: Do these authors refer to the geometric interpretation of Gibbons, Ross, and Shanken (1989)? I don't have access to this paper yet..

Comment: You can see an early version here https://papers.ssrn.com/sol3/papers.cfm?abstract_id=3013149 I believe they do mention GRS (1989)